# How to Format Textfiled.text in Turkish Phone Format?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've a `textfield` which only takes phone number and I'm trying to format it into Turkish format number which looks like this (555) 555 5555. How can I make that in Swift?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var shouldAttemptFormat: Bool = true

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.phoneNumberTextField{
        let resultString: String = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString:string)
        let oldString: String = self.phoneNumberTextField.text
        let oldCount = count(oldString)
        let newCount = count(resultString)
        shouldAttemptFormat = newCount > oldCount
        return true//newCount < 15
    }else{
        return true
    }
        // otherwise we should just let them continue
}

// MARK: - phone number formatting

func formatPhoneNumber() {
    // this value is determined when textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange is called on a phone
    // number cell - if a user is deleting characters we don't want to try to format it, otherwise
    // using the current logic below certain deletions will have no effect
    if !shouldAttemptFormat {
        return
    }

    // here we are leveraging some of the objective-c NSString functions to help parse and modify
    // the phone number... first we strip anything that's not a number from the textfield, and then
    // depending on the current value we append formatting characters to make it pretty
    let currentValue: NSString = self.phoneNumberTextField.text
    let strippedValue: NSString = currentValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9]", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: NSMakeRange(0, currentValue.length))
    var formattedString: NSString = ""
    if strippedValue.length == 0 {
        formattedString = "";
    }
    else if strippedValue.length < 3 {
        formattedString = "(" + (strippedValue as String)
    }
    else if strippedValue.length == 3 {
        formattedString = "(" + (strippedValue as String) + ") "
    }
    else if strippedValue.length < 6 {
        formattedString = "(" + strippedValue.substringToIndex(3) + ") " + strippedValue.substringFromIndex(3)
    }
    else if strippedValue.length == 6 {
        formattedString = "(" + strippedValue.substringToIndex(3) + ") " + strippedValue.substringFromIndex(3) + "-"
    }
    else if strippedValue.length <= 10 {
        formattedString = "(" + strippedValue.substringToIndex(3) + ") " + strippedValue.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(3, 3)) + "-" + strippedValue.substringFromIndex(6)
    }
    else if strippedValue.length >= 11 {
        formattedString = "(" + strippedValue.substringToIndex(3) + ") " + strippedValue.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(3, 3)) + "-" + strippedValue.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(6, 4))
    }
    self.phoneNumberTextField.text = formattedString as String
}
```

I use this code as it looks above, It works. When user type any character, formatPhoneNumber function works, for each char.

```
    self.phoneNumberTextField.addTarget(self, action: "formatPhoneNumber", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

You must to add this line in viewDidLoad.
Hopefully, it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Well if we take the assumption that all Turkish numbers are 10 digits long, we can do it as follows.

First lets define a helper function to get the substrings:

```
func sub(str: String, start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    return str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str.startIndex, start), end: advance(str.startIndex, end)))
}
```

Now we just apply the function to get the sections of the number:

```
// Lets say this is the number we get from the textfield
let number = "1234567890"

let start = sub(number, 0, 3) // "123"
let mid = sub(number, 3, 6) // "456"
let end = sub(number, 6, 10) // "7890"
```

And then we format this into a single string as desired.

```
let formatNumber = "(\(start)) \(mid) \(end)" // "(123) 456 7890"
```

Note that this would only work for numbers that have 10 digits (I doubt that all Turkish numbers are). You would need to modify this to format for numbers of different lengths, by specifying different substrings of the `start` `mid` and `end` above.

If you wanted to limit the user to only using 10 digit numbers, you should perform validation on `textfield`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this on `EiditingChange` method, this will change first three entries to this () format while user inputs text, you can follow same approach to remove format if user is deleting entries

```
 @IBAction func onEditingChanged(sender: UITextField!)
    {
        var string = sender.text as NSString
        if string.length > 3
        {
            let range = string.rangeOfString("(")
            if range.location == NSNotFound
            {
                var firstPart = string.substringToIndex(3)
                var secondPart = string.substringFromIndex(3)
                var string = "(\(firstPart))\(secondPart)"
                sender.text = string
            }
        }
    }
```